# .swf not loading in internet explorer, chrome does in safari, firefox?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

How could it be a SWF is not loading in internet explorer chrome on windows but works fine on firefox and safari on osx?

I called the file like myhomepage.fr/videoplayer.swf

Does this direct all of swf is non supported on IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use some sort of embedding to include your SWF. Behind the scenes, IE was previously just generating a hidden html document to wrap the .swf anyway.

Go with SWFObject: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/